# ASP MVC 4 compilation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting a compilation error which I cannot seem to point the source of. I'm new to ASP MVC and have creating a project to learn MVC.

The error I'm getting is The type 'MVCApp.Domain.Entities.UserGroup' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'MVCApp.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

```
Line 51:         <hr />
Line 52:         <!-- UserGroups -->
Line 53:         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGroups)
Line 54:         @RenderUserGroupsGrid()
Line 55:         <hr />
```

I have a reference to MVCApp.Domain in MVCApp.WebUI project so I'm not sure why I'm even getting this error. It's being triggered at Line 53.

Comment: clean and rebuild your project again and see what happens

Comment: tried this; same thing

Comment: List all your projects in you post - update it.

Comment: Check the '@Model' defined in view

Answer (score 0):

Adding this: to my webconfig solved the problem.

> 

Answer (score 0):

Check the Assembly version with the one mentioned in your web config file.